# How to Sending an email from vb.net console application when a process fails

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using gmail account to send email...when process fail...like this

```
 Dim SimpleSMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com") 
        With SimpleSMTP 
            .Port = 587 
            .EnableSsl = True 
            .Credentials = _ 
            New NetworkCredential("mytest@gmail.com", "passtest") 
            .Send(AnEmailMessage) 
        End With
```

I want to replace this snippet with real smtp details...ussmtp.mysite.com
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just change the URL from `"smtp.gmail.com"` to `"ussmtp.mysite.com"`, make sure the port is appropriate, and setup the credentials as needed.

Otherwise, the code as written should work with any SMTP server.

Comment: How to add cc's and BCC's and distribution lists to the email  programatically in VB

Comment: @nirudyogi It's part of the MailMessage, just like To